# Data is not appending to after clicking the reset button we are again reloading the page for appending the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$("#copyBtn").click(function() {
  var selected = $("#selectBox").val();
  $("#output").append(" Origin :" + selected);
});
$("#copyBtn").click(function() {
  var selected = $("#selectBox1").val();
  $("#output").append("\n Case : " + selected);
});
$("#copyBtn").click(function() {
  var selected = $("#selectBox2").val();
  $("#output").append("\n Customer  : " + selected);
});
$("#copyBtn").click(function() {
  var selected = $("#textbox").val();
  $("#output").append("\n Vendor : " + selected);
});
$("#copyBtn").click(function() {
  var selected = $("#textbox1").val();
  $("#output").append("\n Product : " + selected);
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    /*Clear all input type="text" box*/
    $('#form input[type="text"]').val('');
    /*Clear textarea using id */
    $('#form #output').val('');
    $('#form #selectBox').val('Select');
    $('#form #selectBox1').val('Select');
    $('#form #selectBox2').val('Select');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" class="private-comments-form">
  <div class="col-md-8 formdiv">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 form-group"><label for="sel1">Select Origin of Case</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectBox">
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Customer</option>
          <option>Tech</option>
          <option>Tec</option>
          <option>Account</option>
          <option>Team</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 form-group"> <label for="sel1">Select Case Requestor</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectBox1">
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Vendor</option>
          <option>Contact</option>
          <option>Account</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 form-group"> <label for="sel1">Customer Request</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectBox2">
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Add</option>
          <option>Update</option>
          <option>Remove</option>
          <option>Troubleshoot</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 form-group"> <label for="sel1">Vendor :</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" id="textbox" /></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 form-group"> <label for="sel1">&nbsp;</label> <input class="form-control js-textareacopybtn" id="copyBtn" type="button" value="Get Content" /></div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 form-group"> <label for="sel1">Product :</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" id="textbox1" /></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 form-group"> <label for="sel1">Copy Content :</label><textarea class="col-xs-12 js-copytextarea" id="output" name="textarea"></textarea></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 form-group"> <input type="button" class="reset " id="btn" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

After clicking the reset button , again when we click the Get Content data is not appending 
Am attaching the scripts for both Appending data and Reset Script 
please check the code

Comment: please share the html

Comment: I added the HTML code , Please check

Comment: data is resetting , But after clicking the "Get Button" the data is not copying to Textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation**

Any jQuery code that you plan to use in order to access DOMs (input, textarea, etc). Its better if they are executed inside the `.ready` method.

What this method does its to wait until the whole content of the page is loaded. Then, you can have access to all the DOMs without troubles.

Next, for the `#copyBtn`, you only needed to bind the click events once.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#copyBtn").click(function() {
    var text = " Origin :" + $("#selectBox").val();
    text += "\n Case : " + $("#selectBox1").val();
    text += "\n Customer  : " + $("#selectBox2").val();
    text += "\n Vendor : " + $("#textbox").val();
    text += "\n Product : " +  $("#textbox1").val()
    $("#output").val(text);   
  });

  $('#btn').click(function() {
    /*Clear textarea using id */
    $('#output').val('');
    $('#form #selectBox').val('Select');
    $('#form #selectBox1').val('Select');
    $('#form #selectBox2').val('Select');
    /*Clear all input type="text" box*/
    $('#form input[type="text"]').val('');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" class="private-comments-form">
  <div class="col-md-8 formdiv">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 form-group"><label for="sel1">Select Origin of Case</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectBox">
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Customer</option>
          <option>Tech</option>
          <option>Tec</option>
          <option>Account</option>
          <option>Team</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 form-group"> <label for="sel1">Select Case Requestor</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectBox1">
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Vendor</option>
          <option>Contact</option>
          <option>Account</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 form-group"> <label for="sel1">Customer Request</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="selectBox2">
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>Add</option>
          <option>Update</option>
          <option>Remove</option>
          <option>Troubleshoot</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 form-group"> <label for="sel1">Vendor :</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" id="textbox" /></div>
      
      <div class="col-xs-6 form-group"> <label for="sel1">Product :</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" id="textbox1" /></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 form-group"> <label for="sel1">&nbsp;</label> 

<input class="form-control js-textareacopybtn" id="copyBtn" type="button" value="Get Content" /></div>      

      <div class="col-xs-12 form-group"> <label for="sel1">Copy Content :</label><textarea class="col-xs-12 js-copytextarea" id="output" name="textarea"></textarea></div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 form-group"> <input type="button" class="reset " id="btn" value="Reset" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: After clicking the reset button , again when we click the Get Content data is not appending the data to text area

Comment: @sritejasandela, I updated my answer and solved the issue.

Comment: Thank You So much @acalstein ,From 2 days am strugling with this issue,

Comment: @sritejasandela glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

when you need to add a value to text area you should use `.val()`,
you should get the old value and append what you want to add.
so your JS code should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#copyBtn").click(function() {
    var selected_origin = $("#selectBox").val();
    var selected_case = $("#selectBox1").val();
    var selected_customer = $("#selectBox2").val();  
    var selected_vendor = $("#textbox").val();
    var selected_product = $("#textbox1").val();

    $("#output").val($("#output").val() + " Origin :" + selected_origin);
    $("#output").val($("#output").val() + "\n Case : " + selected_case);
    $("#output").val($("#output").val() + "\n Customer  : " + selected_customer);
    $("#output").val($("#output").val() + "\n Vendor : " + selected_vendor);
    $("#output").val($("#output").val() + "\n Product : " + selected_product);
  });


  $('#btn').click(function() {
    /*Clear all input type="text" box*/
    $('#form input[type="text"]').val('');
    /*Clear textarea using id */
    $('#form #output').val('');
    $('#form #selectBox').val('Select');
    $('#form #selectBox1').val('Select');
    $('#form #selectBox2').val('Select');
  });
});
```

or, if you want to keep your `.append()` as it is (I don't recommend it, cause if anyone edit in the textarea it will not work again),
 so you have to clear the inner HTML for the textarea, not the value (cause in this case you are appending text nodes to your text area not changing it's value)

so you should replace `$('#form #output').val('');` in the reset function with
this 

`$('#form #output').html('');`

or

`$('#form #output').text('');`

and it will also work.